# «Стаканчики да рюмочки доведут до сумочки» — это куда?

Tags: пословицы

Вариация этой пословицы встречается, например, у Даля. Не очень понимаю, к чему здесь сумочка. Что это означает, откуда пошло?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По всей видимости, речь идет о той же самой "сумочке", от которой не стоит зарекаться:

```
От сумы да тюрьмы не зарекайся.
```

Т.е. речь идет о *нищенствовании*.